# Belongs To Association Table Schema Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want each student to be able to post multiple messages on my site.

therefore each student has_many :posts 
and a post belongs_to :student (one student only)

The thing is I can create a record for a student in rails console but can't assign a post to the student ? I am a bit confused. The student model with the has many does not have the attributes from the belongs to model ?

I have a student.rb model

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :gender, :number, :college, :password, :budget, :picture 

  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader 

  has_many :posts
end
```

I have a post.rb model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :message

    belongs_to :student 

end
```

this is my schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130827191617) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.text "message"
  end

  create_table "students", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "number"
    t.string   "college"
    t.string   "password"
    t.float    "budget"
    t.string   "picture"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `student_id` integer column (it would be better if there was also index on this column) to `posts` table.

To do this, you can type in console:

```
bundle exec rails g migration add_student_id_to_posts student:references
```

Comment: I added the `student_id` to my schema, how do you add an index on this student id column to the posts table? can I run a migration and add `t.belongs_to :student` to the posts table?